# 5 tags diferentes para "testes"

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, tags

Existem 5 tags diferentes para "testes":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que nós poderíamos juntá-las numa só, ou talvez em duas.

Comment: Vamos ver opiniões. as acho que só `testes-unitários` e `testes-de-unidade` são repetidos. Talvez `testes-funcionais`. `testes` é algo mais amplo e `tdd` é uma metodologia específica.

Comment: Acho que se resumia tudo em testes e pronto. As descrições são um bocado fracas, todas me levam a pensar em testes e mais nada.

Comment: Concordo com o Jorge, todas parecem estar dentro do escopo de `test-driven-development`

Comment: TDD != Testes. Concordo com o Bigown

Answer (score 2):

Creio que tem que ser separadas mesmo...
Teste de unidade é diferente de Teste Funcional e creio que deveria ser separado mesmo...
Como TDD está dentro de Testes de Unidade, na minha visão pode ficar dentro dela.

Porém é interessante colocar as abreviações de tecnicas como "tdd" e "bdd".
Eu não vejo problema em ter as duas inicialmente citadas mais as abreviações.

Comment: Ou seja, tu apenas juntaria `testes-unitários` e `testes-de-unidade`, como o bigown disse?

Comment: Sim... ficando +- desta forma...
   - testes-unitarios
   - testes-funcionais
   - tdd
   - bdd

E por ai vai...